# change background of layout to anoher image when clicking a button

Tags: android

when i want to change background image to  another image i can't

```
btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bbbn);
    }
});
```

Comment: bbbn is  the name of  an image in drawable-hdpi folder

Comment: Edit the question to include additional info.

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem or error you getting? You should describe your problem and errors as well.

It is very simple, It seems you want to change the background image of a relative layout on button click.

**Here is the activity layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" >
</Button>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn"
    android:background="@drawable/default_image_name" >
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Here is the code for activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button button;
RelativeLayout layout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // Give image name that you want to show on button click
            layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.second_image_name);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Note: Put images on mdpi folder also.